# EJB Webservice EAR working properly in Weblogic 12.1.3 but not working in weblogic 12.2.1

Tags: web-services, ejb, weblogic, weblogic12c, stateless

EJB stateless web service EAR i.e. using @WebService and @Stateless annotation working perfectly in Weblogic 12.1.3 but not working in weblogic 12.2.1, i.e. web service is not getting generated but EAR getting deployed successfully.

I have tried many ways by adding dependent Jars in EAR Lib and also added below in weblogic-application.xml but still web service is not coming.

Please assist.

<wls:prefer-application-packages><wls:package-name>javax.jws.*</wls:package-name><wls:package-name>org.apache.neethi.*</wls:package-name></wls:prefer-application-packages>

Comment: Well, `<wls:package-name>javax.jws.</wls:package-name>` looks suspicious - get rid of that. There's never a reason to package `javax.anything` jars with your application when using full Java EE.

Comment: I am having a similar issue.  Any updates?

Comment: I had the same problem. It's corrected in 12.2.1.2 version of weblogic.

Comment: I am getting this issue in WLS 12.2.1.2.0